# Outlook 2010 attachments go missing

Tags: windows, winforms, email, outlook, email-attachments

I have Windows Forms application which stores lots of documents and other attachments — i.e. a document management system. One of its features is a facility to email a bunch of attachments to a recipient. It does this by simply automating Outlook to compose a new email and we attach all the files to that message, and the user sends the email as normal through Outlook 2010.

Something weird happens. Some of the attachments in the system are actually .msg files (i.e. other emails that have been stored in the document management system). If the email we create contains .msg attachments, when the email arrives at the destination, all attachments are stripped. The really odd thing is that this affects some recipients but not all. But crucially, it only happens when .msg files are in the email's attachments. Provided the email doesn't contain .msg files, it works fine every time.

Any ideas?

here is the code:

```
    Public Shared Sub CreateEmail(ByVal emailAddressTo As String, ByVal subject As String, ByVal bodyText As String, ByVal docs As DespatchDocumentFileList)
        ' create the email
        Dim olApp As Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")   ' New Outlook.Application
        Dim olMail As Object = olApp.CreateItem(0)                  ' Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem

        ' init the email
        With olMail
            .BodyFormat = 2                                         ' Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML
            .Subject = subject
            .To = emailAddressTo
            .Body = bodyText

            For Each doc As DespatchDocumentFileInfo In docs
                Dim DespatchFile As InternalClaimsLibrary.Despatch.DespatchDocumentFile = InternalClaimsLibrary.Despatch.DespatchDocumentFile.GetDespatchDocumentFile(doc.ID)
                Dim FileName As String

                FileName = InternalClaimsLibrary.FileUtils.FileHelper.CreateFileFromByteArray(DespatchFile.DespatchedImageData, IO.Path.GetFileName(DespatchFile.DespatchedFileName))

                .Attachments.Add(FileName)
            Next

        End With

        olMail.Display()

    End Sub
```

Comment: Please share your code you use to add attachments (*e.g. Attachments.Add, etc.*)

Comment: Sure thing - will add as edit to original question

Comment: What is an example `FileName` for the MSG attachment? Can the MSG attachment be opened in your sample code above (*after `.Display`*)?

Comment: Filename could be anything - e.g. email.msg. Yes, we can see all the attachments in the email and when it's sent, in the Sent Items. Something strips off the attachments either as it's going out or as it's coming into the recipient. Any ideas really appreciated.

Comment: If the attachments exist in the **Sent Item** message, can you open them? Try sending the message to another email address (*i.e. yourself*). What is the file size of the embedded MSGs? Do the attached MSGs contain attachments? If it is not affecting all recipients - it must be a mail server stripping them off (*spam filter*)